# dispatchEvent doesn't work in secondary class

Tags: actionscript-3, dispatchevent

I have this problem here:

I have a SWF called *Application.swf* that loads another SWF called *jeu.swf*.
My main class (don't know how to call it haha), is called *Main.as*.
Another class is called *actionObjets.as*

When I call:`dispatchEvent(new MicroJeuEvent(MicroJeuEvent.JEU_TERMINE, 8, ""));` (Provided by my teacher), it works perfectly from Main.as, it works perfectly.

But when I call it from actionObjets, it doesn't work. No error either.

I tried putting this line in a static function, doesn't work either.

Why can I dispatch an Event from my main class and not from another one? I'm not a programmer and I just don't get a few of the basic principles of as3. Is there a way of doing differently? Is so, i'm not good and i'd need to know what to do exactly! haha. Thx!

```
/*--Finir Jeu--*/
        public function finirJeuFonction(methode, points):void{
            var faceDeGagner:Array = new Array("Vous êtes mort","Vous avez sauté par la fenêtre","Vous avez éteind le feux","Vous avez tiré votre soeur déguisée en zombie","Votre soeur aime se déguiser en zombie","Vous avez exterminé l'homme louche");

            switch(monterJeu._Difficulte){
                case 0:
                    _creationObjet.fenetreMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.fenetreMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.armoireMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.armoireMobilier);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    _creationObjet.zombieMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.zombieMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.litMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.litMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.tablePCMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.tablePCMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.coffreMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.coffreMobilier);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    _creationObjet.armoireCoteMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.armoireCoteMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.litMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.litMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.hommeMobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.hommeMobilier);
                    _creationObjet.C4Mobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.C4Mobilier);
                    _creationObjet.boutonC4Mobilier.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet.boutonC4Mobilier);
                    break;
            }
            _creationObjet._creationBackground.getBackgroundStage.parent.removeChild(_creationObjet._creationBackground.getBackgroundStage);
            //Chronometre.horloge.stop();

            _creationObjet.messageFinMC.visible = true;
            _creationObjet.messageFinMC.nbrePointsTxt.text = points;
            _creationObjet.messageFinMC.messageFinTxt.text = faceDeGagner[methode];

            dispatchEvent(new MicroJeuEvent(MicroJeuEvent.JEU_TERMINE, 8, ""));
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for actionObjets?

Comment: actionObjet doesn't do a lot of things (and it's big...), but I added the code where I call it. Edit.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean when you use the actionObjet's addEventListener() method, the Event that is dispatched from actionObjet isn't heard?

Comment: exactly. I don't know why, but I call the same thing in the two (Main.as and actionObjet.as) but it only works in Main.as

Comment: Are you calling actionObjet's finirJeuFonction() before or after the addEventListener? If your calling finirJeuFonction() before, then the Event has dispatched before the event listener can hear it. If that doesn't solve the problem, it would help to see the Main class's code where you call actionObjet's addEventListener() method.

Comment: I'm calling it after! As for the Main class code, I just called it in the constructor (and a few times pretty much everywhere) to see if it would work. It does. It's like if the dispatchEvent had to be in the Main class...

Comment: Are you setting bubbles to true for your custom event?

Answer (score 0):

Try and setup your classes similar to the following:

In the Main class...

```
package 
{
    import com.ActionObjets;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            var actionObjets:ActionObjets = new ActionObjets();
            actionObjets.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            actionObjets.finirJeuFonction(); 

        }// end function

        private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("complete");

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

and in the ActionObjets Class:

```
package com
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ActionObjets extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public function ActionObjets() {} // end function

        public function finirJeuFonction():void 
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE, true));

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

that should work.